# Dropdown list filled from repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, repository, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an MVC3 drop down list that come from this code on the controller.

```
private SelectList progCodesList = new SelectList(new[] { "Description", "Requirements", "Development", "Testing", "Documentation" });
```

How can I fill the fields from a repository, to build the drop down dynamically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the `progCodes` in a database table, with progCode having the text, and progCodeId with a unique id, then you can read the table into a list of `SelectListItem` as follows:

```
private DbContext _db = new DbContext();

var progCodesList = _db.progCodes.Select(x => new SelectListIem()
    {
        Text = x.progCode,
        value = x.progCodeId
    }).ToList();
```

You can then pass this `List<SelectListItem>` to your view either in a strongly-typed model, or using the ViewBag.

Comment: I have the data coming from an XML file via repository, not a DbContext.

Comment: If you have a repository, you can still use a similar style of LINQ query to fill your list. The only difference is in how you are instantiating your repository instance in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the progCodesList to the ViewBag in your controller method using something like:

```
ViewBag.ProgCodeId = progCodesList;
```

Then in your view, you need to fill the drop down like this:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProgCodeId, "ProgCode")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ProgCodeId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProgCodeId)
    </div>
```

Comment: Or for a more type-safe alternative, put it in a strongly-typed view model.

Comment: Thanks for posting about the strongly-typed view model approach. I had forgotten about that.